# if $f \in L^1,$ is there a Riemann integrable $g$ s.t. $f=g$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'm currently studying the basic properties of $L^p$ spaces, and the following question popped to my mind.

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}),$ does it hold that there exists a Riemann integrable function $g$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere? I can't immediately come up with neither a proof nor a counterexample.

Comment: No, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}$ is in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ but being unbounded, it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: If $C$ is a fat Cantor set in $[0,1]$, then $f=\mathbb{1}_C$ is Lebesgue integrable and no Riemann integrable function $g$ equals $f$ almost surely.

Comment: @OliverDíaz ... right, this example is from H.J.S. Smith (1874) which was before Cantor mentioned his set.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks for the historical reference. Always a pleasure to know this kinds of facts.

Answer (score 3):

The following example comes from Carothers. Let $G$ be an open subset of $[0,1]$ containing the rationals in $[0,1]$ such that the outer measure of $G$, $\lambda^*(G)$, satisfies $\lambda^*(G)<1/2$. If $f=1_G$, then $f$ is not Riemann integrable, and also cannot be equal a.e. to ANY Riemann integrable function. See if you can show this! A key result in doing so is that for a bounded function $f$, $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $f$ is continuous at almost every point.

Comment: The function $f=\mathbb{1}_Q$ is not Riemann integrable, it is Lebesgue integrable, and $f$ is indeed equal almost surely to a Riemann integrable function, namely $0$.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for an example of a Lebesgue integrable function that is not a.e. equal to any Riemann integrable function. $1_Q$ is almost everywhere equal to 0, which is R-integrable.